How can I create a TypeScript type for an array that contains exactly one Social field followed by any number of Fields in any order?
I'm working with TypeScript and I have the following types:
type Social = "facebook" | "twitter" | "instagram";
type Fields = "firstName" | "surname";
type PossibleFields = [Social, ...Fields[]];

I want to create a type PossibleFields where the array contains exactly one field from Social and any number of fields from Fields[], but the order doesn't matter.
I know that this solution may not be the most optimal, but I am curious if this type definition is even possible. I want to ensure that:

The array contains at least one Social field.
The array can contain any number of Fields (including none).
The fields can appear in any order.

Is there a way to express this in TypeScript?
Thank you for your help!
I attempted to define the type PossibleFields as follows:
type Social = "facebook" | "twitter" | "instagram";
type Fields = "firstName" | "surname";
type PossibleFields = [Social, ...Fields[]];


Given the small number of the unions' members you could calc all possible tuples (around 30). As a bonus you will have IntelliSense for your typing:
Playground
type Social = "facebook" | "twitter" | "instagram";
type Fields = "firstName" | "surname";

type Insert<
  T extends unknown[],
  U
> = 
T extends [infer F,...infer L]
  ? [F,U,...L] | [F,...Insert<L,U> ] 
  : [U]

type PermutationsOfTuple<
  T extends unknown[],
  R extends unknown[] = T
> = 
T extends [infer F,...infer L]?
  PermutationsOfTuple<L,Insert<R,F> | [F,...R] >
  :R

type OptionalTuples<T, K=T> =
    [T] extends [never]
      ? []
      : K extends K
        ? [] | [K] | [K, ...OptionalTuples<Exclude<T, K>>]
        : never

type PossibleFields = {[K in Social]: [K] | PermutationsOfTuple<[K], OptionalTuples<Fields>>}[Social];


const fields: PossibleFields = ['facebook', 'firstName', 'surname']; // ok
const fields2: PossibleFields = ['surname', 'facebook']; // ok
const fields3: PossibleFields = ['surname']; // Social missing
const fields4: PossibleFields = ['facebook', 'instagram']; // Social doubled


To my understanding, you cannot make a type as you requested as you cannot combine 2 rest elements that are not tuples. Any attempt that will not result in an error, will equivalent to the type (Social | Fields)[]
However, if you only intend to use this as an input, interface field or that sort of usage, you can instead make an assertive generic type such as:
type IsPossibleFields<T> = T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? F extends Social ? (R extends Fields[] ? true : false) : (F extends Fields ? IsPossibleFields<R> : false) : false
type AssertPossibleFields<T> = true extends IsPossibleFields<T> ? T : never

And use it like:
function foo<T = any>(arg: AssertPossibleFields<T>) {/*...*/}

or
interface MyConfig<T = any> {
    field: AssertPossibleFields<T>
} 

